# No handler could be found for logger "dajaxice"

Tags: python, ajax, django

AoA,
    I am trying to make ajax call, when i use function args_example, it posts successfully and I get the response "Message is "... but If I call the function change(same as args_example) I get an error in console(No handler could be found for logger dajaxice)

//ajax.py

```
 from django.utils import simplejson
    from contacts.models import Notifications
    from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register

def args_example(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Message is '})

def change(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Message is '})
```

//Javascript

```
function in template
 setInterval(function(){

      Dajaxice.contacts.change(callback);

  },2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is a django error which is passed via ajax to the browser console. Have a look at `django-dajaxice/dajaxice/core/Dajaxice.py` where Dajaxice defines its own error logger `log = logging.getLogger('dajaxice')` at the top. So what you need to do is to adapt your projects `settings.py` and define this logger with an existing handler e.g.:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    },
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
    'debug_console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'dajaxice': {
    'handlers': ['debug_console'],
    'level': 'WARNING',
    'propagate': False,
    },
}
}
```

Note that this example needs Django >=1.5 because of the `django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue`.

This will of course not solve your porblem but at least you get to the real error message.
For detailed informatin about Django logging please read the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/).

The real django error comes from the fact that `@dajaxice_register` is a method decorator that has to be put in front of every method you want to use in dajax. Change your `ajax.py` to:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from contacts.models import Notifications
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register 
def args_example(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Message is '})

@dajaxice_register 
def change(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Message is '})
```

Comment: thank you for your response! 
I got the console working...but rightly said, I am unable to figure out the problem :(

Comment: I updated the answer to include the solution to the real error message.